# Find when grade changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

my database of grades sometimes refreshes several times a day and it may be the same grade each time if no new grade was entered. The query I have finds the max grade of each day for each course number so now I want to find and display the grade only when it changes, indicating that a new grade has been entered. If anyone could point me in the right direction. Thanks!

```
select distinct convert(date,GradeDate)'Grade Date', 
max(gradescore) 'Grade Score', coursenbr
from resultstbl 
group by Gradedate, coursenbr
order by coursenbr
```

Here are my results:

```
File Date   Current Score   coursenbr
2014-05-11  92.5            111
2014-05-22  92.5            111
2014-05-24  92.5            111
2014-05-12  NULL            222
2014-05-21  75              444
2014-05-23  75              444
2014-05-26  75              444
2014-05-12  50              333
2014-05-21  80.2            777
2014-05-23  80              888
2014-05-26  80              888
2014-05-27  80              888
```

Comment: You could store the results in a table and compare the result set with last stored result, however, this is paractical only for a small set of data. Otherwise, you'll need a create/last changed timestamp column.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an Update Trigger on your table

Answer (score 0):

Query is based on your resultstbl.
Output has CurrentScore, LastScore and a bit flag which indicates wether the score changed since last record or not.

Try

```
SELECT *
    , CASE
        WHEN (sub.[Current Score] <> sub.[Last Score])
        THEN CAST(1 as bit)
            ELSE CAST(0 as bit)
        END
    AS [Score Changed]
FROM
(
    SELECT [File Date]
        , [Current Score]
        , (
            SELECT TOP 1 b.[Current Score]
             FROM resultstbl b
              WHERE b.[File Date] < a.[File Date]
               AND b.coursenbr = a.coursenbr
            ORDER BY b.[File_Date] DESC
        )
        AS [Last Score]
        , [coursenbr]
    FROM resultstbl a
) sub
```